# Octopress blog page not displaying posts

Tags: blogs, octopress

I'm new to Octopress. I created a custom about-me like page as the home page (`source/index.md`) and moved the default `source/index.html` to `/source/blog/index.html`.

In my `Rakefile`, I changed `blog_index_dir` from `source` to `source/blog`.

In `source/blog/index.html` I changed the reference to `/archives` to `/blog/archives`.

In `source/_includes/custom/navigation.html` I changed the links to Blog and Archives to `/blog` and `/blog/archives`.

I haven't deployed my site yet because I'm still working on it, but when I view it using `rake watch` and Pow, my posts show up in the sidebar under Recent Posts, but no posts show up in the Blog page.

The source code for my site is at https://github.com/benlindsay/blog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to change the line in `_config.yml` from
`paginate_path: "posts/:num"`
to
`paginate_path: "blog/posts/:num"`. That fixed the problem.